# Negotiate wait period for my dependent’s tuition

Tags: benefits

I currently have tuition benefits for my child at my employer.  New job offers tuition benefit for dependents but after I work there for 4 years.  But my child is in college now.  Can I negotiate the waiting period for my dependent’s tuition benefits?  Otherwise I can’t afford her to continue at her college.

Comment: I mean, the obvious answer is "yes, you can negotiate"—whether they'll agree is another matter.

Comment: If they say "no" then this should be factored into your move on decision.  You would have to be paid enough money to compensate for this loss of benefits.

Comment: You can try, but it's unlikely to work. Furthermore make sure that your current employer doesn't have a "clawback" clause in your contract or policy. These are actually quite common for that type of benefit. I would take a good look at just sitting it out until your daughter has finished college and any clawback clause has expired.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I negotiate the waiting period for my dependent’s tuition
> benefits? Otherwise I can’t afford her to continue at her college.

You can try and negotiate anything. You do this if the combination of pay and benefits they have offered fall short of what you need to switch jobs.

They also have to decide if the additional benefit you are asking for makes you too expensive.

> New job offers tuition benefit for dependents but after I work there
> for 4 years. But my child is in college now.

Before you make a counter offer, make sure you understand what happens with the benefit you received from the old company. Sometimes they want their money back for tuition if you don't stay for X years after the last time the benefit was received.

That may mean that switching could be more expensive than you are considering.

If they do agree with adding the benefit make sure the offer letter is updated to reflect that benefit, so that when you apply for the money the system doesn't reject you.

Answer (score 1):

First, if the new conditions are not working for you, then why move.

If your new pay is higher but you have to pay for college for the next four years.  Then work it out and see which way you come out better.

Then you can decide whether you still want this job.

But you can always negotiate.  Just be upfront and request them to pay you the benefit earlier or raise your pay, as you will have to take a financial hit to work for them.

Comment: You can always _try_ to negotiate. They can always say no. Which brings you back to deciding whether the move makes sense or not.